# Trying to send AWS SNS json message in Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, post, postman, amazon-sns

When I try to send a POST request via Postman for publishing a message to AWS SNS, I get a "400 Bad Request, the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax".

In the "publish" action - there is an option for a regular message to a topic (which I can get to work), and an option for a json formatted message, which can change the message according to the different notification protocols, and it seems that I am sending the json in the parameter in a bad way.

Help on this matter?

Screen shot of my POST request from postman:

[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrhgl.png)

Also Tried the following json in the Message parameter: {\"default\": \"default\"}

Comment: you aren't including a post body - everything is going to the query string...

Comment: when I tried to add a body it didn't recognize it, shouted that everything is empty (topic, message, etc..)

Comment: when I try to send a regular message, not json based with the parameters in the query string it succeeds

Comment: if you can share a body example that is working it will be great!